# JQuery Creating Array from All Inputs and Extracting It

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oaw755cy/1/)

**Here is my Input Code :**

```
<input type="text" id="first" name="first">
<input type="text" id="second" name="second">
<input type="text" id="third" name="third">
<input type="text" id="fourth" name="fourth">
<input type="button" id="driver" name="driver" value="Submit">
```

**Here is my Script :**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#driver").click(function(event) {
            var A = $("#first").val();
            var B = $("#second").val();
            var C = $("#third").val();
            var D = $("#fourth").val();
            console.log(A);
            console.log(B);
            console.log(C);
            console.log(D);

        });
    });
</script>
```

There was few fiddle which can create just an array in few complex ways i.e.,

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    var results = [];
    var items = $('[name^=item]');
    $.each(items, function(index, value) {
        value = $(value);
        var jsObject = {};
        jsObject[value.attr('name')] = value.attr('value');
        results.push(jsObject);
    });
    console.log(results);
});
```

**But Is there a simple way to create an Array with all elements and Extract all the values from the from those Array in JQuery ??**

Comment: what is the structure of the array you are looking for... is it just a array of values?

Comment: I mean to get just array of values ( i have given input only as the text, but needed to construct array for any input type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simplest way :-

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var arr=[]; //you can make 'arr' as local or global as you want
        $("#driver").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();  //disable default behaviour of #driver
            var A = $("#first").val();
            var B = $("#second").val();
            var C = $("#third").val();
            var D = $("#fourth").val();
            arr.push(A);  //store values in array with .push()
            arr.push(B);
            arr.push(C);
            arr.push(D);
            console.log(arr);  //print array
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `$.map()` instead of `array.push()`

```js
var textboxes;

var extract = function() {
  var arr = textboxes.map(function() {
    return this.value; //textbox value
  }).get(); //get array
  console.log('text boxe values: ', arr);
};

$(function() {
  textboxes = $('input:text'); //get all text boxes
  $('#driver').on('click', extract);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="first" name="first">
<input type="text" id="second" name="second">
<input type="text" id="third" name="third">
<input type="text" id="fourth" name="fourth">
<input type="button" id="driver" name="driver" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Thanks i shall use it too :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a simple selector and each?

```js
$('#driver').on('click', function() {
  var fields = [];

  $('input, select').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is('[type=checkbox]')) {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        fields.push($(this).val());
      }
    } else if ($(this).is('[type=radio]')) {
      if ($('[name=' + $(this).attr('name') + ']:checked').get(0) === this) {
        fields.push($(this).val());
      }
    } else if (!$(this).is('[type=submit], [type=button]')) {
      fields.push($(this).val());
    }
  });

  console.log(fields);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="first" name="first">
<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="fineprint" />Did you read the print?
<br />
<input type="text" id="second" name="second" />
<br />
<select>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type="text" id="third" name="third" />
<br />Test?
<br />
<input type="radio" name="bool" value="yes" checked />Yes
<br />
<input type="radio" name="bool" value="no" />No
<br />
<input type="text" id="fourth" name="fourth" />
<br />
<input type="button" id="driver" name="driver" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Suppose if i have any select box or check box, **$('input[type=text]').each(function() {** this only will work ?

Comment: No. Those aren't `[type=text]` elements. If you want to get the value of a different types of inputs, you'll have to use different methods. You only want to get the values of checked checkboxes, for example. Search the site for how to get the values of other types or ask another question for more info.

Comment: Went ahead and added support for just about everything since your title did imply ALL inputs. Removed buttons and the submit button, though.